# How to edit the metadata from a MKV file whith Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metadata, python-module, mkv

I was wondering if there is any module or something in Python which is able to not only retrieve, but also write/edit metadata of MKV/Matroska files (the names of the audio tracks and the title, mainly).

I have downloaded some seasons of some TV shows and then I have created scripts to rename the files based on ep. + season numbers and title (like s1e29 - Episode Name) (title, which is the episode name being retrieved via BeautifulSoup from the series Wiki page). So far I managed to do all  but editing the metadata.

The closest I came to what I'm looking for was the [enzyme](https://pypi.org/project/enzyme/) module, which allows one to (only) retrieve metadata from MKV files and, currently, I am manually editing the metadata with MKVToolNix. I've been doing everything via scripts and ""webscraping"", however, so I wanted to approach this the same way.

Comment: An idea could be to using the python subprocess module and then mkvpropedit.

Comment: you could try automating this task via shell scripting, not python, using the mkvtoolnix CLI (mkvpropedit, as referred by @ElidorDD). I'm very happy with that, as I'm too into mass organizing media files (mainly mkv and m4a).

Answer (score -1):

Just a quick example of a batch file:
FOR %%i IN (dir *.mkv) DO mkvpropedit.exe "%%i" --edit info --set "title=%%~ni"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).